# Java Swing recursive layout

Tags: java, swing, layout

I know this might seem like a duplicate, but I'm not getting anywhere with by experimenting on invalidate/validate/revalidate/repaint, so please bear with me. My panel structure looks something like this:

```
JPanel/GridBagLayout (1)
+-- JPanel/BorderLayout
    +-- JPanel/GridBagLayout (2)
    |   +-- JTextField (3)
    |   +-- JComboBox
    +-- JPanel/WhateverLayout
    ...
```

... and so forth. In my sub panel `(2)` I change the insets (right and bottom), and I want to layout the whole top panel `(1)`. Is there some easy way to layout everything (preferably from top panel `(1)` and down, but anything that works is okey). Right now I've tried combinations of invalidate/validate/revalidate/repaint on all levels, but nothing seems to work (in fact nothing changes at all). Thanks!

**Edit:** I found out that `GridBagLayout` clones the `GridBagConstraints` as components are added, so the reason my code didn't work by running revalidate and friends was that I updated the wrong constraints. I found and added a solution to this problem below.

Comment: Have you tried the inv/val/reval from the parent of the top panel (maybe the frame or something)? I've found that sometimes gives it the "kick" it needs to do a relayout.

Comment: @Ash: no I haven't, but I would prefer not to, as it would be quite expensive, since the hierarchy is very big with a ton of components in it. But I'll definitely try it, thanks!

Comment: @Ask: that didn't work as the problem actually had not much to do with (re)validate, I added an edit paragraph to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` clones the `GridBagConstraints` as components are added (that's why changing my original once had no effect on the layout), so I extended `GridBagLayout` to be able to update the actual constraints runtime. The code below sets the layout margins depending on type of component, and if "expanded", which is what I use to toggle between two modes:

```
public class ExpandableGridBagLayout extends GridBagLayout {

    public void setExpand(boolean expanded) {
        for (Map.Entry<Component, GridBagConstraints> entry : comptable.entrySet()) {
            setExpandedMargin(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), expanded);
        }
    }

    private void setExpandedMargin(Component component, GridBagConstraints constraints, boolean expanded) {
        constraints.insets.right = 2;
        if (component instanceof JLabel) {
            constraints.insets.top = expanded ? 3 : 0;
            constraints.insets.bottom = expanded ? 3 : 0;
        } else {
            constraints.insets.bottom = expanded ? 8 : 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Then all I had to do was to call `panel.revalidate()` on `(1)` and layouting works as expected.

Comment: hmm ... this is not an answer, or is it? If it's additional info to your question, better edit the question and add it there. Plus an SSCCE so we can see what you _really_ do :-)

Comment: +1 for excelent GBC workaround, I'd suggest to add `panel.repaint()`too, not required for all J/Components

Comment: @kleopatra: You are right, the question was fuzzy. "In my sub panel (2) I change the insets" should be extended with the clarification "which where originally used to add the components with" in order to grasp that was part of the problem. I assumed that the problem was in the layout, when it actually was in updating the wrong instances of the insets.

Comment: @mKorbel: it should not be required as I actually don't change the looks of anything, just the insets. And it is currently working, that is usually a good sign. :)

Comment: somewhere on this forum is described for which type of J/Component required, not about Look and Feel or Graphics, but sometimes repaint() missed in the important methods implemented in the API

Comment: ahh ... so it _is_ an answer, after all - my bad in not understanding it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

- for re_layout whole `JFrame`(`JDialog` e.i.) is there `JFrame#pack()`
- for fill available area in the container (after `remove` / `add`) is there `revalidate()` and `repaint()`
- you have to decide for which of containers in the `Components hierarchy`

code example about `pack()` & `(re)validate()` & `repaint()`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class AddComponentsAtRuntime {

    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JCheckBox checkValidate, checkReValidate, checkRepaint, checkPack;

    public AddComponentsAtRuntime() {
        JButton b = new JButton();
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
        b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 10));
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(b);
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(panel, "Center");
        f.add(getCheckBoxPanel(), "South");
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getCheckBoxPanel() {
        checkValidate = new JCheckBox("validate");
        checkValidate.setSelected(false);
        checkReValidate = new JCheckBox("revalidate");
        checkReValidate.setSelected(false);
        checkRepaint = new JCheckBox("repaint");
        checkRepaint.setSelected(false);
        checkPack = new JCheckBox("pack");
        checkPack.setSelected(false);
        JButton addComp = new JButton("Add New One");
        addComp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton b = new JButton();
                b.setBackground(Color.red);
                b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));
                b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 10));
                panel.add(b);
                makeChange();
                System.out.println(" Components Count after Adds :" + panel.getComponentCount());
            }
        });
        JButton removeComp = new JButton("Remove One");
        removeComp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int count = panel.getComponentCount();
                if (count > 0) {
                    panel.remove(0);
                }
                makeChange();
                System.out.println(" Components Count after Removes :" + panel.getComponentCount());
            }
        });
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(checkValidate);
        panel2.add(checkReValidate);
        panel2.add(checkRepaint);
        panel2.add(checkPack);
        panel2.add(addComp);
        panel2.add(removeComp);
        return panel2;
    }

    private void makeChange() {
        if (checkValidate.isSelected()) {
            panel.validate();
        }
        if (checkReValidate.isSelected()) {
            panel.revalidate();
        }
        if (checkRepaint.isSelected()) {
            panel.repaint();
        }
        if (checkPack.isSelected()) {
            f.pack();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                AddComponentsAtRuntime makingChanges = new AddComponentsAtRuntime();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't add/remove components, I just change the insets (more or less).

Comment: this is simple to simulating on this example, and I hope that we talking about Insets from GridBagLaoyut, SpringLayout e.i. not from AbsoluteLayout, never mind works for NullLayout too, really is not possible to see something (that make me sense) without seeing your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: We are talking GridBagLayout, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Still not entirely sure about your exact context, but judging from your "answer" you seem to be changing component constraints on the fly. To trigger a re-layout of the effected parts, you need to

- invalidate the child/ren whose constraints had been changed (note: it's *not* enough to invalidate the parent), this will bubble up the hierarchy as needed
- validate an appropriate container up the hierarchy

Snippet:

```
ExpandableGridBagLayout bag = panel2.getLayout();
bag.setExpand(true);
for(Component child: panel2.getComponents())
    child.invalidate();
panel1.validate();
```

There is no public api to recursively invalidate everything below a given container (invalidateTree is package private). A quick hack is to temporarily toggle the font of the parent container (which internally messages invalidateTree)

```
/**
 * Invalidates the component hierarchy below the given container.<p>
 * 
 * This implementation hacks around package private scope of invalidateTree by 
 * exploiting the implementation detail that the method is internally 
 * used by setFont, so we temporary change the font of the given container to trigger
 * its internal call.<p>
 * 
 * @param parent
 */
protected void invalidateTree(Container parent) {
    Font font = parent.getFont();
    parent.setFont(null); 
    parent.setFont(font);
}
```

**EDIT**

Don't know which part of this answer you exactly mean by *incorrect* - obviously I couldn't solve your problem without any detailed knowledge about it ;-)

Curious me is wondering how a revalidate up in the hierarchy would lead to a re-layout of valid grand/children: validate/Tree clearly stops at a valid component. Below is a code-snippet to play with

- it's a two-level hierarchy, a parent with two children
- the action changes layout-effecting properties of the sister under its feet (we change v/hgap of the layout) and revalidate the parent

The outcome varies, depending f.i. on the LayoutManager of the parent

- with FlowLayout nothing happens ever,
- with BoxLayout it may be validated, depending on

  - whether the horizontal or vertical gap was changed *and*
  - the direction of the Box

Looks like a relayout of a valid child might be (or not) a side-effect of a relayout higher up - without any guarantee to happen and hard to predict. Nothing I want to rely on ;-)

```
final JComponent sister = new JPanel();
final Border subBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED);
sister.setBorder(subBorder);
sister.add(new JTextField(20));
sister.add(new JButton("dummy - do nothing"));

JComponent brother = new JPanel();
brother.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
brother.add(new JTextField(20));
// vary the parent's LayoutManager
final JComponent parent = Box.createVerticalBox();
// final JComponent parent = Box.createHorizontalBox();
// final JComponent parent = new JPanel();
parent.add(sister);
parent.add(brother);

// action to simulate a change of child constraints 
Action action = new AbstractAction("change sub constraints") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        FlowLayout layout = (FlowLayout) sister.getLayout();
        layout.setHgap(layout.getHgap() * 2);
      //  layout.setVgap(layout.getVgap() * 2);
      //  sister.invalidate();
        parent.revalidate();
    }
};
brother.add(new JButton(action));

JFrame frame = new JFrame("play with validation");
frame.add(parent);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: This is incorrect, all I had to do was to update the insets of the copied constraints and call revalidate of the owning JPanel. I'll update my answer to clarify.